# How to display dates (in string type) in the format 'Mon, Sep 12 2:30AM AEDT' or local time zone?

Tags: angular, timezone

I am finding it difficult to display a set of dates (string datatype) with timezone.

This is my date JSON:

```
{
    "startDate": "2016-09-04T21:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2016-09-05T05:00:00Z"
}
```

I am unable to show it this way `'Mon, Sep 05 2:30AM IST'`, i.e. to display the timezone according to the user's location. I tried using the built-in `DatePipe` as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-12"> {{ startDate | date:'EEE, MMM dd h:mma Z' }}</div>
```

But this gives:

```
Mon, Sep 05 2:30AM GMT+5:30
```

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)? Do you convert that string into a JS date object at any point? What have you done, and what happened when you did it; could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: This is how I used with builtin Pipe -

<div class="col-xs-12"> {{ startDate | date:'EEE, MMM dd h:mma Z' }}</div>

where startDate = "2016-09-04T21:00:00Z";
And this is how I am getting in UI " Mon, Sep 05 2:30AM GMT+5:30"

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Comment: I meant edit it to actually include that additional information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) the built-in `DatePipe` timezone options are `'Z'` for the GMT offset (`GMT+1`, in my case) or `'z'` for full name (`British Summer Time`). If you wanted to have a different representation, you could do it with a custom pipe, e.g.:

```ts
import { LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customDate'
})
export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  datePipe: DatePipe;

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {
    this.datePipe = new DatePipe(locale);
  }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let fullTimezone = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'z');
    let rest = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'EEE, MMM dd h:mma');
    let timezone = fullTimezone.match(/[A-Z]/g).join('');
    return `${rest} ${timezone}`;
  }

}
```

Here I've assumed that the timezone representation you want is the initials, i.e. the capital letters in the full timezone name (**B**ritish **S**ummer **T**ime -> BST). Then you can use that pipe in your HTML: `{{ startDate | customDate }}`. This also prevents you needing to repeat the format all over your codebase, in the likely event that you want a consistent date format everywhere.

To test the pipe, set it up in a `TestBed`:

```ts
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CustomDatePipe } from './custom-date.pipe';    

describe('CustomDatePipe', () => {
  let pipe: CustomDatePipe;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ 
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-GB' },
        CustomDatePipe
      ]
    });

    pipe = TestBed.get(CustomDatePipe);
  });

  it('should do whatever you want it to do', () => {
    expect(pipe.transform('...').toBe('...');
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you could look into [`moment-timezone`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), which provides a lot of features for dealing with dates and times.

Comment: And one more query, as to how we write karma for testing the date format?

Comment: @AryaK have you had some specific problem with writing a test? You can call the transform method directly with different inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I am very new on these concepts, so please pardon me for asking silly questions :) The way i tried is like this, 


 it('create an instance', () => {
    let value = "2016-09-04T21:00:00Z";
    let pipe = new CustomDatePipePipe( "2016-09-04T21:00:00Z");
    expect(pipe.transform(value)).toEqual('Mon, Sep 05 2:30AM IST');
    console.log("value", pipe.transform(value));
    });

Comment: @AryaK ...and what happened? For one thing, you don't initialise the pipe with the value, you initialise it with the *locale*, and pass the value to `transform`. See the example I've added.

Comment: Hi John,i didn't quite understand the unit test that you have written. Guess i need to know  a lot more about TestBed for me to proceed with coding in Jasmine.

Comment: @AryaK yes, you won't be able to properly test components without it